# Can't get json template working for WSO2 DSS Data Service

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I can get JSON output from XML formatted data service by just asking for JSON in the header.  However, to eliminate the extra fields that the XML format adds, I'd like to specify the JSON template as suggested in the documentation.  However, when I do so, get the following response:

```
{"Fault":{"faultcode":"soapenv:Server","faultstring":"Error while writing to the output stream using JsonWriter","detail":""}}
```

Is there something wrong with my template string?

Here is the XML of the Data Service:

```
<data name="sqldb1201xferJson" transports="http https local">
 <config enableOData="false" id="transfer1">
  <property name="driverClassName">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="url">jdbc:sqlserver://MyDb:1;databaseName=mydb;integratedSecurity=true</property>
</config>
<query id="transfer1" useConfig="transfer1">
  <sql>select TransferId, description from transfer where TransferId &gt; 7048</sql>
  <result outputType="json"> {"one":{"TransferId":"$TransferId","description":"$description"}}&#xd; </result>
</query>
<operation name="transfer1Op">
   <call-query href="transfer1"/>
</operation>
<resource method="GET" path="TransferId/{TransferId}">
  <description>none                                    &#xd;                                    </description>
  <call-query href="transfer1"/>
</resource>
</data>
```

Comment: Would you please mention the WSO2 DSS version that you are using?

Comment: We need more information. Could you paste the contents of WSO2Carbon.log's contents for this request?